# Universal instantiation on a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Okay first of all I suck with the terminology and wouldn't mind if someone could help me understand the difference of Universal, Existential and Instantiation, Generalization. I'm trying to go from a set notation to an existential generalization(?). I don't need anyone to solve it for me, just help me get it to the right format.

I have to prove $(A-B)-C \subseteq A-(B-C)$ and I'm going at it through direct proof. Is this correct?

$\forall x$| $((x\in A$ v $x\notin B)$ v $x\notin C)$ -> $(x\in A$ v $(x\notin B$ v $x\in C))$ $Universal$ $Instantiation$

$p(x) = x\in A, q(x) = x\in B, r(x) = x\in C$

$\forall x$| $((p(x)$ v $¬ q(x))$ v $¬ r(x))$ -> $(p(x)$ v $(¬ q(x)$ v $r(x)))$

$∃ c$| $((p(c)$ v $¬ q(c))$ v $¬ r(c))$ -> $(p(c)$ v $(¬ q(c)$ v $r(c)))$ $Existential$ $Generalization$

Then direct proof from there, is all of this right?

Comment: **No** : $x \in (A−B)$ **iff** $∀x (x∈A \land x∉B)$ with **and**.

Comment: You can prove it "semi-formally"... but if you **have to** use formal logic rulse, you have to start with *Universal Instantiation* and conclude with *Universal Generalization*.